# Where should Android PopupWindow event handlers go?

Tags: android

I'm using an Android PopupWindow in an application so I want to be sure I understand what "best practice" is for handing events from it.

My PopupWindow has a button and currently the onClick handler for that button is in the same Activity thats launched the popup.

But I've seen an example where someone created a class which extend PopupWindow.   That's the class they create when they need a PopUpWindow, but they still put the onClick handler in the Activity that launched it.

If I had a separate class like that, extending PopupWindow, would it be better to put the button handler in that class, and if so how would I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it really matter. Personally, for legibility, I create a new class [file].

Comment: But creating a new class (i.e., ... extends PopupWindow) doesn't really answer the question.  PopupWindow is not derived from the Activity class, so would it be better to put the handler in the invoking Activity class, or in the new PopupWindw-derived class?

Comment: My mistake I miss read your question. For more clarification, are you talking about the 'onClick handler' that launchs the PopupWindow, or responds to a click event <em>in</em> the PopupWindow?